# How to run programs in Windows in a linked way as in terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, tkinter, terminal, pyinstaller, command-prompt

I want to run a .exe file in windows (which I basically obtained using PyInstaller on a Python script in Windows). The exe, on running, pops a GUI window, where the user fills in some data.

I want that when the user click the close button, the GUI window gets destroyed and the remaining script continues to perform computation on data and log it somewhere (command prompt maybe?). The problem is that the process gets killed (or whatever it is technically called in Windows) when I click the close button.

This is particularly easy in Ubuntu, as when the Linux executable file of the same script (again obtained using PyInstaller on the script in Ubuntu 16.04) is run using the Terminal, clicking the close window does not kill the entire process but only acts as an event to trigger the later execution. Logging happens in the same terminal instance.

Is it possible to achieve this in Windows (maybe I can link the execution to command prompt or something)? I will be grateful if the answer draws parallelism with Ubuntu, as I am a beginner in Windows and only know the basics. Even if I use a dedicated button to submit the data, how can I close the GUI window (because it is not needed any more) and get the log from the later part of execution.

If it is of use:

- The GUI is created using tkinter module.
- The data from the user is actually used to poll a server, so log of the poll count is necessary for me to know that the program is running well.

Update 1: Minimum repr eg -

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text = "Close this window and you should see counting upto 10 in log")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()

# close clicked => root destroyed
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i)
```

Comment: You can try and log it into a file and then use that file, I think the same shall work also it will be better if you provide a [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer Updated. Also, is there any other way than logging in a file, something like the Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: What options you pass to PyInstaller in Windows?

Comment: @acw1668 I compile it using - pyinstaller <myfilename>.py --onefile --windowed

Comment: If you want a console, remove `--windowed`.

Comment: @acw1668 It worked! Thank you very much! Now I run it using command prompt  - start <filename> and it shows exactly the same behavior as terminal in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @acw1688, removing the `--windowed` flag solved the problem.